# How calculing the difference for each begin and end - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I would like to calcul the difference for each begin/end in a new df, here is my df:

```
 Flag                     Timestamp
begin   2019-10-21  07:48:26.740378
end     2019-10-21  07:48:28.449916
begin   2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045
end     2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466
begin   2019-10-21  07:57:59.223986
end     2019-10-21  07:58:00.774449
```

So my new df must looks like :

```
New_df
1.709538
4.383421
1.550463
```

Thank you, for your time !

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Idea is create 2 column DataFrame by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), so for final DataFrame only subtract columns:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

df = df.set_index([df.groupby('Flag').cumcount(), 'Flag'])['Timestamp'].unstack()

New_df = df['end'].sub(df['begin']).dt.total_seconds()
print (New_df)
0    1.709538
1    4.383421
2    1.550463
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but in the compilation I have this problem : 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @ThonyNadhir - Dataa re not converted to datetimes, add `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])`